# How TS generics return record or simple value according to type of param?

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to write a function whit proper type support, and with the following requirements:

- When `key` is passed as single string, the return value should a
  simple object or whatever, delivered by `V` generic type
- When `key` is passed as array of strings, the return value should be  Record (or map/dictionary/whatever) of `V` generic type

Given the following snippet:

```
function get<K extends string | string[], V>(key: K): K extends string ? V : Record<string, V> {
    /**
     * Implementation
     * ...
     */
}
```

Result:

```
const result1 = get('key'); // result1: unknown
const result2 = get<string, {}>('key'); // result2: {}
const result3 = get<string[], {}>(['key1', 'key2']); // result3: Record<string, {}>
```

I'd like to eliminate the explicit type decalaration for `key` here. So I can focus only on the return type of `get(...)`.

Expected:

```
const result1 = get('key'); // result1: unknown - doesn't matter
const result2 = get<{}>('key'); // result2: {}
const result3 = get<{}>(['key1', 'key2']); // result3: Record<string, {}>
```

I've tried a couple of ways, but it wasn't worked as I expect.

Is there any best (or better) practice for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try overload?

```
function get<V>(key: string): V;
function get<V>(key: string[]): Record<string, V>;
function get<V>(key: string |string[]): any {
    return 'whatever you want';
}

const result1 = get('key'); // result1: unknown
const result2 = get<{}>('key'); // result2: {}
const result3 = get<{}>(['key1', 'key2']); // result3: Record<string, {}>
```

Comment: I agree with the overload, but there's no need to return `any` in the base case. You can return `V | Record<string, V>`.

Comment: It actually does not matter here, since typescript does not use base function to infer types. You can even write it in the most generic form `function get<V>(key: any): any {`.

Comment: It does if you call it with a parameter that is itself `string|string[]` (for example, if another generic function calls this one).

Comment: I don't see the behavior you mentioned in TS4.1.

Comment: Sorry, I was just retesting, and you're correct you need the additional prototype. But that allows it to be called from generic code. `function get<V>(key: string |string[]): V | Record<string,V>;` (but noted that this is probably rare. I write it this way, but it is likely not common)